# MS outlook 2013 automatically closing and restarting continuously

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2013

MS Outlook 2013 automatically closes and restarts continuously. When I checked the Event Viewer, I found the below mentioned error. Kindly check and provide the solution for the same.

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 15.0.4420.1017, time stamp: 0x506742d6
Faulting module name: outlph.dll, version: 15.0.4997.1000, time stamp: 0x5a2f8819
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000a0cf
Faulting process ID: 0x20a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d44fd9c4b1b947
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\outlph.dll
Report ID: 6f6fa814-fe5e-4541-83b3-d85beffabf17
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting outlook in safe mode.

To do this click the start button and type outlook /safe ﻿then press return, any add-ons or plugins you do have wont load, if it's stable the next thing will be to remove the offending one.

MS support should have done this with you though